# How to solve indeterminations of the type $0/0$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am unable to find these limits:

1)
$$
\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{3(1 - x^2) - 2(1 - x^3)}{(1 - x^3)(1 - x^2)}
$$

2)
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1 - 2x - x^2} - (x + 1)}{x}
$$

3)
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x + 2} + \sqrt{x + 6} - \sqrt{6} - \sqrt{2}}{x}
$$

4)
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - \sqrt[3]{1 - x}}{1 + \sqrt[3]{3x - 1}}
$$

My interest is not in the answers, but in the algebraic manipulations i can use to eliminate the indeterminations of the type $0/0$.

*My english skills are not so good, i'm sorry for this.*

Comment: It doesn't look like these will be fixable by standard algebraic manipulations - you should use L'Hopital's rule (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Hopital%27s_rule).

Comment: The top one at least can be factored.

Comment: These are too many. Please choose one of them.

Comment: @Amr I disagree. If they are related to have the same general approach, then it makes sense to have all these questions in one problem, so responders know what techniques to be supplying

Comment: @user45150 Yes but if they can be solved by a similar technique then it suffices to show how one of them is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For 1) Notice that $x=-1$ is a zero of the numerator and denominator polynomials.
  So we can divide both terms by $x-1$, e.g. using polynomial long division. We get
  $$\begin{equation*}
  \frac{3(1-x^{2})-2(1-x^{3})}{x-1}=\frac{2x^{3}-3x^{2}+1}{x-1}=2x^{2}-x-1
  \end{equation*}$$
  $$\begin{equation*}
  \frac{(1-x^{3})(1-x^{2})}{x-1}=\frac{x^{5}-x^{3}-x^{2}+1}{x-1}
  =x^{4}+x^{3}-x-1,\end{equation*}$$
  both of which can be divided again by $x-1$
  $$\begin{eqnarray*}
  \frac{2x^{2}-x-1}{x-1} &=&2x+1 \\
  \frac{x^{4}+x^{3}-x-1}{x-1} &=&x^{3}+2x^{2}+2x+1.
  \end{eqnarray*}$$
  We thus have
  $$\begin{equation*}
  \frac{3(1-x^{2})-2(1-x^{3})}{(1-x^{3})(1-x^{2})}=\frac{2x^{2}-x-1}{
  x^{4}+x^{3}-x-1}=\frac{2x+1}{x^{3}+2x^{2}+2x+1}.
  \end{equation*}$$
  So
  $$\begin{equation*}
  \lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{3(1-x^{2})-2(1-x^{3})}{(1-x^{3})(1-x^{2})}
  =\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{2x+1}{x^{3}+2x^{2}+2x+1}=\frac{1}{2}.
  \end{equation*}$$
  *Alternatively* we can use the identities
  $$\begin{eqnarray*}
  1-x^{2} &=&(1-x)(1+x) \\
  1-x^{3} &=&(1-x)\left( x^{2}+x+1\right) 
  \end{eqnarray*}$$
  to  *factor* both terms as follows:
  $$\begin{eqnarray*}
  \frac{3(1-x^{2})-2(1-x^{3})}{(1-x^{3})(1-x^{2})} &=&\frac{
  3(1-x)(1+x)-2(1-x)\left( x^{2}+x+1\right) }{(1-x)\left( x^{2}+x+1\right)
  (1-x)(1+x)} \\
  &=&\frac{3(1+x)-2\left( x^{2}+x+1\right) }{\left( x^{2}+x+1\right) (1-x)(1+x)
  } \\
  &=&\frac{-2x^{2}+x+1}{\left( x^{2}+x+1\right) (1-x)(1+x)} \\
  &=&\frac{-2(x+\frac{1}{2})(x-1)}{\left( x^{2}+x+1\right) (1-x)(1+x)} \\
  &=&\frac{2(x+\frac{1}{2})}{\left( x^{2}+x+1\right) (1+x)}.
  \end{eqnarray*}$$
- For 2) Expand the fraction and multiply the new fraction by the
  *conjugate* of the numerator
  $$\begin{eqnarray*}
  &&\frac{\sqrt{1-2x-x^{2}}-(x+1)}{x} \\
  &=&-1+\frac{\sqrt{1-2x-x^{2}}-1}{x} \\
  &=&-1+\frac{\left( \sqrt{1-2x-x^{2}}-1\right) \left( \sqrt{1-2x-x^{2}}
  +1\right) }{x\left( \sqrt{1-2x-x^{2}}+1\right) } \\
  &=&-1+\frac{1-2x-x^{2}-1}{x\left( \sqrt{1-2x-x^{2}}+1\right) }=-1-\frac{2+x}{
  \sqrt{1-2x-x^{2}}+1}.
  \end{eqnarray*}$$
  Hence
  $$\begin{equation*}
  \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sqrt{1-2x-x^{2}}-(x+1)}{x}=-1-\lim_{x\rightarrow
  0}\frac{2+x}{\sqrt{1-2x-x^{2}}+1}=-2.
  \end{equation*}$$
- For 3) expand the fraction into two and multiply each one by the *conjugate* of the numerator:
  $$\begin{eqnarray*}
  &&\frac{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x+6}-\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{x} \\
  &=&\sqrt{2}\frac{\left( \sqrt{x/2+1}-1\right) }{x}+\sqrt{6}\frac{\left( 
  \sqrt{x/6+1}-1\right) }{x} \\
  &=&\sqrt{2}\frac{\left( \sqrt{x/2+1}-1\right) \left( \sqrt{x/2+1}+1\right) }{x\left( \sqrt{x/2+1}+1\right) }+\sqrt{6}\frac{\left( \sqrt{x/6+1}-1\right)\left( \sqrt{x/6+1}+1\right) }{x\left( \sqrt{x/6+1}+1\right) } \\
  &=&\sqrt{2}\frac{1/2}{\sqrt{x/2+1}+1}+\sqrt{6}\frac{1/6}{\sqrt{x/6+1}+1}.
  \end{eqnarray*}$$
  Thus
  $$\begin{eqnarray*}
  &&\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x+6}-\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{x} \\
  &=&\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \sqrt{2}\frac{1/2}{\sqrt{x/2+1}+1}+\sqrt{6}\frac{1/6}{\sqrt{x/6+1}+1}\right)  \\
  &=&\frac{1}{12}\sqrt{6}+\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{2}.
  \end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 1):

1) Factorise both the numerator and denominator so that the terms $(1-x)^n$ can be simplified 
2) Use $$\alpha-\beta=\frac{\alpha^2-\beta^2}{\alpha+\beta}$$
3) Write

$$
\sqrt{x + 2} + \sqrt{x + 6} - \sqrt{6} - \sqrt{2}=(\sqrt{x + 2}  - \sqrt{2})+ (\sqrt{x + 6} - \sqrt{6})
$$
and use what we did in $2$.

4) Use $$\alpha-\beta=\frac{\alpha^3-\beta^3}{\alpha^2+\alpha\beta+\beta^2}$$